# How to print variable name from function argument using {{}} in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, user-defined-functions, tidyeval

I am new to R and trying to understand functional Programming and use of `{{}}`.

**I am not able to figure out how to just `print` the name of `variable_name` from argument without `!!, enquos`**

I have tried below code but that doesn't work as expected:

```
summarise_min <- function(data, var_min, var_group) {

  print({{var_min}})
  
  print(glue("test_{{var_min}}"))

}

summarise_min(mtcars, mpg, cyl)
```

Have looked at some examples from : https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html but its implementation is mostly in `summarise / group` functions:

```
my_summarise5 <- function(data, mean_var, sd_var) {
  data %>% 
    summarise(
      "mean_{{mean_var}}" := mean({{ mean_var }}), 
      "sd_{{sd_var}}" := mean({{ sd_var }})
    )
}
my_summarise5(mtcars, mpg, cyl)
```

I am trying to avoid use of `!!, enquo, quo_name` as they are very confusing.

Is there no way to work this out just by using `{{}}` and are they only limited to summarise functions?

Comment: (This is meta-programming, not functional programming btw)

Comment: @LionelHenry Thanks for letting me know!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{{` works exclusively in tidyverse *data-masking* functions. `print()` and `glue()` are not such functions.

You can do `print(enquo(var))`. This (1) defuses `var` and prevents it from being evaluated; (2) prints the defused expression.

You could also create your own function to print a variable by wrapping this pattern:

```r
print_arg <- function(arg) print(enquo(arg))
```

Since it uses the tidy eval operator `enquo()`, it automatically supports `{{`. You can call it like this:

```r
print_arg({{ some_arg }})
```